# Is a table scan occurring when when a new row is inserted into my table?

Tags: sql-server

How can I tell that a table scan is occurring when a new row is inserted into my table? What should I be looking for as far as schema of my table goes?

Assuming a table like this:

```
              People
|-----------------------------------|
| ID  Name  Age  CreatedOn  OrderID |
|-----------------------------------|
| 1   Foo   18   12/30/17   5       |      
| 2   Bar   21   5/30/17    10      |
|-----------------------------------|
```

- Clustered Index on `ID`
- Non-Clustered Index on `Name`

If I insert a new row:

```sql
insert into People values('Jane', 30, '10/30/17')
```

1. What sort of insertion logic is going on here under the hood? Does it have to do a scan of the table on each insert due to the CI or the Non-CI?

What if my Non-CI is defined as:

```sql
create nonclustered index [IX_People_Name] on People ( [Name] asc )
include ([OrderID])
```

2. Does this do anything to the speed of an insert on the table?

Comment: I'm not sure that a full table scan happens, but the index needs to be updated.  Think of updating a B tree and what that would entail.

Comment: Check your query plan to see if a table scan happens. Even if happens now it may not in the future and vice versa. If you have under a certain amount of rows (say 10000), a table scan always happens cause that's the fastest

Comment: yes index do affect insertion in negative way if you hv less index and number of rows insetion is less then it very minor to notice. If you hv any constraint , define then it does evaluate it,thus making it slower.fill factor also affect dml ,because of page split.Since your CI is identity field ,new row will be inserted in the end.